# Convert ISO 8601-formatted time period to ticks / milliseconds

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date, time

Is there a built-in way in .NET 3.5 to convert an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) period into a .NET TimeSpan / ticks / milliseconds?

Comment: @Timwi: I am a great fan of brevity. However, I am also a naturally friendly person. So what is wrong with wishing everyone a good day at work?

Comment: because the style of SO (and other Stack Exchange network sites) is to not do so. For discussion use http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: By removing it, I am not indicating that it is not friendly. It’s just that it doesn’t really contribute anything to the question. Remember that this is not a discussion forum with individualised posts.

Comment: @Richard / Timwi: Understood, accepted and will adhere to it in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing directly built into .NET unfortunately.

And there is no `TimeSpan.ParseExact` before .NET 4 which could be used if the components of the string are known.

Comment: flagged answered for being the first to answer.

Answer (score 6):

[`XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.totimespan%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) seems to have been around forever and does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Even if there is nothing directly in the .Net framework i found that [Joda.org](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_iso.html) has implemented such a thing and i remembered that [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) did a port of it to .Net called [noda-time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/).

A first view into [this source code](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Format/IsoPeriodFormats.cs) shows that he implemented something here for this purpose. Maybe you should do some further investigations in this project.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way. To further complicate things [ISO 8601 durations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) is in fact totally incompatible with TimeSpan or any other exact way to measure time. The reason is that ISO 8601 durations can contain years and months. The problem with that is that a year can have 365 or 366 days and a month 28 to 31 days. Joda-Time [solves this](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html) problem by relating such inexact periods to an instant in time.

Unless you are lucky and the Periods happen to use the P[YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]T[hh]:[mm]:[ss] format because then you just:

```
string period = "P0003-06-04T12:30:05";
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Parse(period.Remove(0,1)).Ticks);
```

Comment: For my specific task this should normally be something like "PT1S" or "PT0.05999999999S", so parsing isn't a real problem. Just wanted to get a good solution for it. Thanks for your answer!